# webread giving different results than 'View Page Source' of webpage

Tags: matlab, web-scraping, youtube, httprequest

I am doing some web scraping from a YouTube page using MATLAB. However the `webread` function of MATLAB is giving different results as compared to when we 'view page source' of that web page. I have used the following code.

```
d = webread('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqqc1GmsuANsx3s3Y0CBsQ/playlists?view=1&sort=dd&shelf_id=0')
```

What am I doing wrong? I need the exact text as can be seen in 'view page source' of that page.

Answer (score 2):

The difference likely stems from a different [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP) that is used by your MATLAB vs your browser. Here's an example that illustrates this:

```matlab
% Default request (MATLAB's UA):
URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4jsmvNoXP4&list=PLk1Sqn_f33KuS7ZSVMJqzFaqOyyl-esmG&index=2';
data = webread(URL);

% Custom user-agent (Firefox UA):
UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';
wo = weboptions('UserAgent', UA);
data2 = webread(URL, wo);

% Comparison:
disp(numel(data))
disp(numel(data2))

%{
Result:
      243203
     2794189
%}
```

As you can see, by only changing the `'UserAgent'` string, we managed to get a drastically different reply from the website (web service).

I cannot guarantee that this is the exact information you get in your browser, but if you want to improve your chances of getting the same response, the first thing you should do is use the **exact same** user agent as the browser you're using. If you're not sure what your browser's user agent is, the [whatismybrowser](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/) website has a collection of various user agents to choose from.

P.S.
I used a slightly different YouTube URL since the playlist you linked is inaccessible for me (or doesn't exist).